# Database error from manage.py: "TypeError: invalid postgreSQL type: bigint"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-south

One of my servers recently started having an error when trying to use any of the south related commands from manage.py

```
$ python ./manage.py migrate
TypeError: invalid postgreSQL type: bigint
$ python ./manage.py syncdb
TypeError: invalid postgreSQL type: bigint
$ python ./manage.py shell
TypeError: invalid postgreSQL type: bigint
```

The setup: django, postgis, south, ubuntu.

The confusing part is that nothing has changed on this server recently, and 3 other servers with what should be the exact same setup are working correctly.

I turned on postgres statement logging, but i'm not seeing any obvious errors there:

```
2013-09-24 16:33:14 UTC LOG:  statement: SHOW default_transaction_isolation
2013-09-24 16:33:14 UTC LOG:  statement: SET default_transaction_isolation TO DEFAULT
2013-09-24 16:33:14 UTC LOG:  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'
2013-09-24 16:33:14 UTC LOG:  statement: SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed'
2013-09-24 16:33:14 UTC LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2013-09-24 16:33:14 UTC LOG:  statement: SELECT postgis_lib_version()
```

from settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'redacted',
        'USER': 'redacted',
        'PASSWORD':'...',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

postgres versions:

```
psql (9.1.9)
Type "help" for help.

redacted=# select version();
                                                  version
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
(1 row)
redacted=# select postgis_lib_version();
 postgis_lib_version
---------------------
 2.0.1
(1 row)
```

Django-1.5.4

Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the bug was caused by another module djorm-ext-pgarray, which had been updated on the server with the error, but not on the other servers.  I was able to find the cause of it by greping through python modules for the error message.

It was a quick fix in the module(1 line of code), deployed initially by adding a local copy of the module, and then by sending a pull request to the module author.

The moral of the story: beware of upgrading modules with pip.